# webserver inside elastic beanstalk delivers empty page. "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, directus

Heyo,

I have deployed a directus instance via elastic beanstalk.
The beanstalk generated URL can access the site, any element however cannot be loaded due to "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" and thus delivers a blank page. I believe
that I need to adjust my load balancer / security group settings but I do not know in what way.

The application port is 8055

Here is my config:

[Load Balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNKe0.jpg)

[Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzqci.jpg)

Am I missing something obvious?